# how would you test a bitcoind/bitcoin-cli without syncing?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-cli

I want to be able to test bitcoin without waiting literal days, is it possible to run a local node that doesnt require sync?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use regtest e.g. `bitcoind -regtest` which is a local node without any prior block history.

But even with mainnet, testnet, signet nodes you can still run most bitcoin-cli commands during IBD (initial block download). You can't use some Core wallet functionality (e.g. spending) until IBD has completed as the wallet needs to know how much Bitcoin it has etc.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just for trying I recommend using the testnet. No matter if testnet or mainnet, you could install a pruned node.

> Pruned nodes, a type of full node that allows us to take advantage of their enormous security, but reducing their blockchain storage requirements so that we can run them on practically any device. [Source](https://academy.bit2me.com/en/what-is-a-pruned-node/)